# return interval to 1 variable and the currentTime propery of the audio element to another variable

Tags: jquery, setinterval, html5-audio

The function in question is playTime(). i need to store the timer to `$time0` so i can clear it when the user pauses the song. i also need to get the `currentTime` property of the audio element returned to `$time`. I need the time so i can display the song position, and also catch network errors so i can resume playback at the same position of the song the error occured, minimizing skips in the playback caused by network errors. I've played around with returning them from the same function, but for some reason i am unable to accomplish it, as the timer continues after the song is paused.

The second part of my question is, How does one go about rounding a float up to the closest whole number(int) in javascript? is it even possible?

```
var $audio = $(".audio-player");
$audio.trigger('load');
$audio.prop('volume',.50);
var $time = 0;
var $time0 = 0;
function playTime(){
    $time0 = setInterval(function(){
        console.log($audio.prop('currentTime'));
        $time = $audio.prop('currentTime');
    },1000);
}
$audio.on('progress',function(e){
    console.log('playback started');
});
$audio.on('play',function(e){
    playTime();
});
$audio.on('pause',function(e){
    clearInterval($time0);
});
```

Comment: A demo would be useful.

Comment: @StathisG coming right up...

Comment: @StathisG i setup a fiddle but its not loading the audio. http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/yp50jqr8/10/

Comment: I just tested it in Chrome. The audio is loading ok, and the pause/play buttons are operating as they should (the play button is resuming the track from the point it was paused). As I can see in the console, when you click pause the time stops increasing; that's probably why the track resumes at the time it should. I noticed though that the play event (line 17) is triggered more than once, and one of the intervals doesn't stop (it keeps printing the time). I'm too tired to figure out why right now; have a look and I'll get back to it tomorrow if no one provided a solution in the meantime.

Comment: @StathisG thank you for taking a look at it. go get some rest brother.

Comment: yw; I edited my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the second part of your question, i.e.:

> How does one go about rounding a float up to the closest whole
>   number(int) in javascript?

You can use [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil). Examples:

```
Math.ceil(.95); // 1
Math.ceil(7.004) // 8
```

Regarding the 1st part, as I already mentioned in a comment, I noticed that in the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/yp50jqr8/10/) you provided the play event was being triggered more than once, causing the interval to being set more than once. This is solved if instead of triggering the play/pause events using jQuery's `trigger` function, you use the native play and pause functions.

```
$audio.trigger('play'); //line 56
$audio.trigger('pause'); //line 60

//the above should become:

$audio.get(0).play();
$audio.get(0).pause();
```

By the way, the above didn't affect the actual play & pause functions; everything seem to work properly.

Having said that, since your goal is to keep the current time in a variable, the `audio` element provides a native way to do that, using the [`played` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-played), which returns a [`TimeRanges`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges) object containing this information.

For example, your pause handler could become:

```
$audio.on('pause',function(e){
    $time = $(this).prop('played'); //you can either store the whole element, or just the end value (see console.log example)
    //$time = $(this).get(0).played; //just an alternative of the above
    console.log($time.end(0)); //this will print the paused time
});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: `Math.floor` would probably be a better method to use in this case.

Comment: @idbehold He wants to always round up, at least that's what I understood. `Math.ceil(7.2)` will return 8, where `Math.round(7.2)` will return 7.

Comment: @StathisG I'm trying to keep the time in the variable, in case of network/playback errors so i can catch the errors and resume playback at the last time prior to the error. I never investigated whether currenTime would retain the value, as the network errors were so rare i haven't caught one since it happened originally. thanks for the tips about play and pause. really useful information.

Comment: fortunately, i was able to fix the issue thanks to your answer. preciate it.